# How to get the latitude and longitude of the computer that enters my website using PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

I've tried this:

```
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

But it doesn't work. I would like a solution that doesn't rely on outside libraries. Thank you!

Comment: Google Maps doesn't know where your user is either. It can help you turn a street address to lat/lon or vice versa, it can't tell you where your user *is*.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: @user128 has posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You will need GeoIP data. One source is here http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Theres no other way to know, and even GeoIP cant be 100%

When you have the city you will need to geocide that  which should just plug in to the `$address` variable that you have now